Scheme is affine if and only if a certain open cover is affine.
$\newcommand{\O}{\mathscr{O}}\newcommand{\Spec}{\operatorname{Spec}}$Let $X$ be a scheme, and $\{f_1,\dots, f_n\}\in \O_X(X)$ generate the unit ideal. Set:
\begin{align}
X_{f_i}=\{x\in X:(f_i)_x\notin \mathfrak m_x\}
\end{align}
I want to show that:
$$X\text{ is affine}\Leftrightarrow X_{f_i}\text{ is affine for all $i$}$$
One direction is obvious as then the $X_{f_i}$ are distinguished opens. If $\O_X(X)=A$, then for the other direction, it suffices to show that $X_{f_i}=\Spec A_{f_i}$ for all $i$, as then the natural map $X\rightarrow \Spec A$ is an isomorphism on an open cover.
Let $\O_X(X_{f_i})=A_i$, so that $\Spec A_i=X_{f_i}$. One easily verifies that for any open affine $U=\Spec B$, that $U\cap X_{f_i}=U_{f_i|_U}=\Spec B_{f_i|_U}$, so it follows that:
$$X_{ij}=X_{f_i}\cap X_{f_j}=\Spec A_{ij}$$
where $A_{ij}=(A_i)_{f_j|_{X_{f_i}}}=(A_j)_{f_i|_{X_{f_j}}}$.
The restriction map $\theta^X_{X_{f_i}}:A\rightarrow A_i$ takes $f_i$ to an invertible element in $A_i$, so there is a natural map $\phi:A_{f_i}\rightarrow A_i$ given by $a/f_i^k\mapsto 
a|_{X_{f_i}}\cdot(f_i|_{X_{f_i}})^{-1}$. I believe we need to show this is an isomorphism, but I am at a loss of how to do so.
I imagine we should leverage the sheaf axioms, and I saw a hint which said to look at the exact sequence of $\O_X(X)$ modules:
$$0\longrightarrow \O_X(X)\longrightarrow \bigoplus_j\O_X(X_{f_j})\longrightarrow \bigoplus_{j<k}\O_X(X_{jk})$$
but I am not sure how either of these actually help us in this case. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Those requirements are not enough. You need the open sets to cover $\operatorname{Spec} \mathscr O_X (X)$ instead of $X$ itself.

@Trebor Ok, I see what you mean: we need them generate the unit ideal so that we can actually check that the natural morphism $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}A$ is locally an isomorphism on a cover of $\operatorname{Spec}A$. However, that part is not important (as far as I can see) to the crux of the proof which is showing $A_i=A_{f_i}$.

@Trebor I have edited the post to reflect this fact.

Does this help? In case you didn't know, this is an exercise in chapter II of Hartshorne, so it has been asked about before.
